# Borrar archivos con google-apps-script

Tags: google-apps-script

Se tiene una hoja de cálculo de google y un script que genera archivos PDF con la información de la hoja de cálculo, los archivos PDF se guardan automáticamente en una carpeta de google drive.
Como se podría automatizar el borrado de los archivos PDF de esa carpeta.
Adjunto código.

```
    function Hojascalculo() {
var sheetName = "HOY";
var folderID = "123456789"; // Identificador unico de carpeta.
var pdfName = "Informe salidas dia "+Date();

var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);

//Copia hoja de calculo
var destSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(DriveApp.getFileById(sourceSpreadsheet.getId()).makeCopy("temporal_pdf", folder))

var sheets = destSpreadsheet.getSheets();
for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
if (sheets[i].getSheetName() != sheetName){
destSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(sheets[i]);
}
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de ayuda necesitas? Por favor incluye un __[mcve]__ que permita comprender qué estás haciendo y a qué error te enfrentas. Sigue esta guía _[ask]_. En este momento tu pregunta no es clara y podría ser puesta en espera de que la arregles.

Comment: @toledano Pide un script que borre los archivos de una carpeta a determinada hora. Está muy claro lo que se pregunta. Poner un ejemplo MCV no es obligatorio. La pregunta es mejorable. Pero no hay ningún motivo para cerrarla.

Comment: Igualmente considero que es una pregunta interesante y que merecería quedar abierta.

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos, la pregunta quedó resuelta con la respuesta de A.Cedano. Excelente comunidad !!!

Comment: Para evitar que la pregunta sea cerrada, podrías modificarla, preguntando solamente por un script que borre todos los archivos de una determinada carpeta. Además, se adapta mejor al formato del sitio, ya que estarías planteando una pregunta, no dos. Lo de ejecutar el script a una hora determinada es relativamente fácil. Si no logras hacer esa parte podrías plantear otra pregunta sobre _cómo ejecutar un GAS a una hora determinada_. Planteadas así las preguntas serán más útiles a futuros usuarios. Saludos.

Comment: La pregunta no muestra lo buscado/investigado como se requiere en [ask]. Por otro lado, este no es un servicio de búsqueda de información por otros, ni de solicitud de scripts.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos: Estoy de acuerdo que no es obligatorio un MCVE, pero la pregunta no es el tipo de publicaciones que queremos en este sitio, es una solicitud del tipo "háganlo por mí", similar a las malas preguntas sobre tareas escolares.

Comment: @A.Cedano: Para compartir código hay muchas opciones, de hecho tenemos un hilo en meta sobre herramientas que se pueden usar para eso, el cual entiendo que conoces muy bien pues tu eres el OP.

Comment: @A.Cedano aunque la pregunta no es mala, no dice que busco o que cosas intento. solo dice quiero el script. Y eso la hace una mala pregunta. Y no. no es un sitio para compartir codigo per-se, es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas.. y aunque tu respuesta es grandiosa (como la mayoria de las que das) la pregunta es mala, y deberias esperar a que OP la mejore o llegue a un stardard de calidad para contestarla.

Comment: Se modificó la pregunta, gracias por el aporte.

Comment: @JoseSantiago: El código que has agregado no aporta nada a la pregunta. Como mencionas algunos, no en todas las preguntas es necesario incluir código. Lo que sí es importante es incluir lo que has buscado/investigado y si has intentado algo como solución de la pregunta mencionarlo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Existen dos posibilidades:

1. Borrar el archivo definitivamente
2. Enviar el archivo a la papelera

El código tiene activada por defecto la primera posibilidad, mientras que la segunda está comentada:

```
function borrarTodosEnFolder() 
{

  /*Colocar ID del folder*/
  var folderId = '0B...';

  var thisFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  thisFile = thisFolder.getFiles();

  while (thisFile.hasNext()) 
  {
    var eachFile = thisFile.next();
    var fileId = eachFile.getId();    

    /* Si sólo se quiere enviar a la papelera */
    //eachFile.setTrashed(true);

    /* Para removerlo definitivamente usar remove de la API de Drive antes activada :) */

    Drive.Files.remove(fileId);

    Logger.log("Se removió el archivo: " + eachFile.getName());
  };

}
```

---

Nota:

Para que la opción 1 funcione, debes activar [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive)  en Google Apps Script.

Los pasos son:

- Ir la opción `Recursos` del menú superior
- Ir a `Servicios Avanzados de Google`
- En la pantalla que se abrirá, *encender* Drive Api

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te dirá que debes tener la Api activada en tu proyecto de la Consola. Si ya la tienes activada no tienes que hacerlo.

- Click en `Aceptar`

Ahora podrás usar la API de Drive (y cualquier otra que actives)  en Google Script.

Fíjate las opciones que te dará cuando escribas por ejemplo: `Drive.` :)

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona a la perfección.